# ReactJS Routes not working with Apache server

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-router-dom

So I have checked every article and webpage I could find.
I cannot get this to work.

I am simply trying to do this:

```
<a href="/subpage" >Click Here for Sub Page</a>
```

It works when I use yarn start but does not work when I build it. (yarn build)
I can view my main webpage, but all the  hrefs do not work
404 Not found error.

Here is my .htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /mywebpage/index.html [QSA,L]
```

Here is my package.json:

```
  "name": "mywebpage",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://mywebpage.com",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.16",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my App.js

```
import Home from './Home';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import SubPage from './SubPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <main className="App">
      <Router basename="mywebpage">
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/subpage" element={<SubPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For my webserver,
http://mywebpage.com points to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:####/mywebpage
I also have the www setup for it. Both bring up my normal webpage, but no links can be clicked.

Comment: Where are you trying to use `<a href="/subpage" ></a>`? What `react-router` `Link` components are not clickable? What other links are not clickable? Please include all relevant code you've an issue working with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It is simply a render with a line for the subpage right now. It works without using the yarn build, I updated the line to express what is says, I forgot the text

Comment: I don't see how `yarn` or the `react-router-dom` tag is relevant.

Comment: I did not tag yarn, but I am using Route from react-router-dom, and that is what I cannot get to work. Maybe my problem isn't related with Route?

Comment: Do the routes render if you navigate directly to them (*i.e. via the URL in the address bar*)? Instead of raw anchor tags try rendering `Link` components to link to your routes.

Comment: They do if I use yarn start. They do not if I use yarn build and deploy it in apache. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: If you change your code to actually render `Link` components do they work when the app is deployed? They should just work regardless of the server as the server and the .htaccess file are really only relevant when navigating directly to a sub-route that isn't the directory where the app is hosted. Are there any errors?

Comment: I am not sure how to render the Link components? And where would I create them?

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/link

Answer (score 0):

Using a

```
<Link to="/login"> subpage</Link>
```

fixed the issue for me.